# $\prod_{i=1}^n(x-a_i)\in Z[x]$ implies $\prod_{i=1}^n(x-a_i^m)\in Z[x]$, for $m>0$

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Suppose $P(x)\in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ splits as $\prod_{i=1}^n(x-a_i)$ in $\mathbb{C}$. Show that, $P_m(x) = \prod_{i=1}^n(x-a_i^m)$ for any $m>0$ is also in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$.(Hint: show that the coefficients lie in $\mathbb{Q} \cap \bar{\mathbb{Z}}$, where $\bar{\mathbb{Z}}$ is the ring of algebraic integers over $\mathbb{Q}$
). Also, if $\forall i,\;\vert a_i\vert\leq 1$, show that we can bound the coefficients of the polynomial $P_m(x)$ independently of $m$.
I have tried and proved this result for $m=2$, but in general how to approach this problem. I did try induction, but I am stuck. Please can any one give a hint to solve the problem? I know I have to use the relation between roots and coefficients of a polynomial, but I am not getting exactly how to use it.

Comment: Use the fact the coefficients of $P$ are elementary symmetric polynomials of $\mathbb{Z}[a_1, \ldots, a_n]$. But the coefficients of $P_m$ are again (non-necessary elementary) symmetric polynomials of $\mathbb{Z}[a_1, \ldots, a_n]$. Apply the fundamental theorem of symmetric polynomials to conclude.

Comment: What you call the relations between roots and coefficients are precisely the elementary symmetric polynomials in $a_1, \ldots, a_n$.

Comment: Yes thank you I got it

Comment: How to prove the second part of the question where we needed to show that the coefficients are bounded? @Halbaroth

Comment: If $|a_i| \leqslant 1$ then $|a_i^m| \leqslant 1$. Each coefficient of $P_m$ is an element of $\mathbb{Z}[a_1^m, \ldots, a_n^m]$. Let $c = P(a_1^m, \ldots, a_n^m)$ such a coefficient. Then $|c| \leqslant \mathrm{sup}_{\mathbb{D}^n} |P|$.

Comment: How to find the bound, is $#a$, s.t. $\vert a\vert\leq 1$ and $a$ is integral finite? According to your comment there exists a bound, but is it always computable?

Comment: In my last comment the function $P$ is an elementary symmetric polynomial. Thus computing its supremum on $\mathbb{D}^n$ is easy.

Comment: By $\mathbb{D}^n$ you mean the unit disk right?

Comment: It is the unit polydisc in $\mathbb{C}^n$, which is the unit ball for the maximum norm on $\mathbb{C}^n$,

Comment: Thanks a lot...